# How do I enable case-sensitive matching (6th parameter, boolean) on .fnFilter();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatables

I am having the same problem as [fnFilter value 'Active' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185532/fnfilter-value-active-not-working). My reputation is not high enough to comment so I'll ask here:

- How do I enable case-sensitive matching (6th parameter, boolean)?

```
    filterActivate: function (table) {
        $(table).dataTable().fnFilter("Active", 7, true);
    },

    filterAll: function (table) {
        $(table).dataTable().fnFilter("", 7, true);
    },

    filterInactivate: function (table) {
        $(table).dataTable().fnFilter("Inactive", 7, true);
    },
```

Comment: It sounds like you should pass a sixth parameter of `false` (because the sixth parameter is `bCaseInsensitive` - `.fnFilter("Active", 7, true, true, true, false)`

Comment: However,  because you are treating your input string as a regex, it will effectively be case-sensitive.